# Почему какие-то странные символы в html странице скачанной с гитхаба?

Tags: python, html

Я скачал [веб-страницу](https://github.com/pythontoday/scrap_tutorial/blob/master/lesson1/blank/index.html) с гитхаба, и все символы нормально отображались в файле, но когда я выводил в консоль через питон там были какие-то странные символы.
Например вот тег title:
В файле: `<title>Главная страница блога</title>`

При выводе в консоль: `<title>Р“Р»Р°РІРЅР°СЏ СЃС‚СЂР°РЅРёС†Р° Р±Р»РѕРіР°</title>`

Я создал свой html файл и все было нормально.
Почему так происходит?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html

Comment: сам текст - в utf-8, а выводите как cp1251. либо перекодируйте, либо используйте нормальное средство вывода

Comment: Можно узнать ответ на мой вопрос, а не ссылку?

Comment: спасибо, я решил свою проблему!